# IHostedService(s) registered using Autofac and constructor parameters can not resolve when the ASP.Net Core application runs

Tags: .net, .net-core, autofac, .net-6.0

In Asp.Net core 6...

I am trying to register a service that implements IHostedService using Autofac.  The constructor of this service has parameters that I need to register using ResolvedParameters.  The problem is that when that application runs, the constructor parameters of MyService cannot be resolved.  If I add .As to the Autofac registration and remove build.Services.AddHostedService<..> the service starts but the controller cannot be instantiated

```
public class MyService : IHostedService
{
    public MyService(IMessageSubscriber subscriber) {...}
}

// in my autofac module  MyAutofacModule.cs
protected override Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
builder.RegisterType<QueueSubscriber>.Keyed<ISubscriber>("MyServiceQueue")
.WithParameter (new TypedParameter(typeof(QueueConnectionInfo), "some connection info")).SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
.WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(pi,cc) => pi.Name = "subscriber",
                                    (pi, cc) => cc.ResolveKeyed<IMessageSubscriber>("MyServiceQueue")
)).SingleInstance();
}

in Program.cs

builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(containerBuilder => {containerBuilder.RegisterModule(MyAutofacModule)});

builder.Services.AddHostedService<MyService>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

app.Run()

With this setup I'll get an error complaining that the parameter "subscriber" could not be resolved when trying to create the hosted service.

If I add .As to the setup in the Autofac module and remove the services.AddHostedSerivce line the app starts but my controller that is looking for a paramater of type MyService can no longer be created.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this or what the issue may be?

Answer (score 0):

From the snippet it looks like you have an `ISubscriber` and an `IMessageSubscriber`, so that's a potential point of confusion.

- `MyService` takes an `IMessageSubscriber`
- `QueueSubscriber` is registered as a *keyed* `ISubscriber`

  - That's a different type
  - You can't resolve an un-keyed dependency from a keyed dependency registration
- I think `AddHostedService` is going to re-register (and, thus, override) the DI registration for `MyService`, so it's possible that whole keyed thing is getting ignored anyway.

There isn't any way to "fix" `AddHostedService` - it is what it is. I don't remember what's inside that exactly, so you'd need to go spelunking in the .NET GitHub repos (the beauty of open source is you can go find that stuff).

Likely you'll need to figure out a way to allow an unkeyed dependency to be injected into your hosted service. Maybe that means you have to create indirection, like an `IMessageSubscriberProvider` that *can* take the keyed dependency, then you inject that provider into the hosted service. You'll have to get creative.